# Arduino Continue with for-loop only when button is pressed

Tags: c++, for-loop, arduino

I have an int array of melodies. If i press the button it plays the whole song but if i put a break after the `delay`, than it just reset the `i`. How do i make it so that only after another button-press it continues? (i'm still a newbie at this sorry and thanks in advance)

```
int buttonPin = 12;

void setup() 
{
 // put your setup code here, to run once:

   pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}


void loop() 
{
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody); i++)
  {
    if(buttonState == HIGH)
    {
      tone(8, mariomelody[i], 70); 
      delay();
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: This might not be an answer but your button might be high as default. Post code where you set up digital pin.

Comment: @Gox If it was, than the melody would be played immediately...

Comment: i dont have arduino with me, but my advice is always put this `digitalWrite(buttonPin, LOW);` in setup. also try putting it before if statement.

Comment: Now I get your quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the loop while the button press is still held in:

```
int buttonPin = 12;

void setup() 
{
 // put your setup code here, to run once:

   pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}


void loop() 
{
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody); i++)
  {
    if(buttonState == HIGH)
    {
      tone(8, mariomelody[i], 70); 
      delay();
    }  
    while(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
    // wait until the button is released
    }
    while(digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW)
    {
    //wait until the button is pressed again
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to play the melody while the button is pressed, and stop if the button is released.

Then it would be something like:

```
int i = 0;
void loop() 
{
    if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
      tone(8, mariomelody[i], 70); 
      i = (i + 1) % sizeof(mariomelody);
      delay();
    }  
}
```

To avoid resetting the position to the begin of the melody you need `i` to be a global variable.

If you want the button to switch on and off the melody you'll need another global variable `playing`:

```
bool playing = false;
void loop()
{
    if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
        playing = !playing;
        while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
             ; //wait for release
    }
    if (playing) {
        //the rest is the same
    }
}
```